# Get Url from Dailymotion for LiveStream

Tags: javascript, m3u8, dailymotion-api, geturl

Over here I can see **liveStream** in the browser, how do you get it running on **VLC** player?
unfortunately tried several and it did not work out.
maybe you have a tip for me

or knows your other possibility possibly via curl or PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- 1. Load DailyMotion API (Javascript) -->
<script src='https://api.dmcdn.net/all.js'> </script>

<!-- 2. Create container for DM Player instance  -->
<div id='player'></div>

<!-- 3. Javascript stuff goes here -->
<script>

  //Set VIDEO_ID (retrieve or update from your CMS)
  //**example** var VIDEO_ID = get_video_id.php **where PHP returns/echo the text of ID**

  var VIDEO_ID = "xwr14q"; //update this via your CMS technique

  //Create DM Player instance//
  var player = DM.player(document.getElementById('player'), {
    video: VIDEO_ID,
    width: "100%", height: "100%",
    params: { autoplay: false, mute: true }


  });

  //Handle video ending (seek back to zero time)//
  player.addEventListener('end', function (evt) { evt.target.currentTime = 0; evt.target.play() } );

  //Control functions for DM Player instance//
  function func_Play()
  { player.play(); }

  function func_Pause()
  { player.pause(); }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to read a live stream is to use the dailymotion official player.

We do not allow access to live streaming apart from our player.

Comment: How can i download a video using dailymotion api ?

Answer (score 0):

and whats that? Youre alowwed to download videofiles from dailymotion

[Download dailymotion video using video id with different quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538111/download-dailymotion-video-using-video-id-with-different-quality/54961977)

Comment: This is an unofficial way to get a video. We don't encourage you to use it and it could be not working in the futur.